# How to position and center text in PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I need the "Job Setup Sheet" centered under the Heading. How should that be done?

Here is what I tried:

```
// Create an empty page
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
page.Size = PageSize.Letter;
// Get an XGraphics object for drawing
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

//XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode,
                                                PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

// Create a font
XFont HeadingFont = new XFont("Times New Roman", 20, XFontStyle.Bold);
XFont BodyFont = new XFont("Times New Roman", 12);
// Draw the text
gfx.DrawString("Texas Exterior Systems", HeadingFont, XBrushes.Black,
  new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
  XStringFormats.TopCenter);

gfx.DrawString("Job Setup Sheet", BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
  new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
  XStringFormats.Center);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The XRect you pass to DrawString always covers the whole page. By providing the correct top and/or bottom position with the rect, the text can be drawn at that position.

Sample code can be [found here](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_text_in_different_styles_17):

```
void DrawText(XGraphics gfx, int number)
{
    BeginBox(gfx, number, "Text Styles");

    const string facename = "Times New Roman";

    //XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
    XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.WinAnsi, PdfFontEmbedding.Default);

    XFont fontRegular = new XFont(facename, 20, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
    XFont fontBold = new XFont(facename, 20, XFontStyle.Bold, options);
    XFont fontItalic = new XFont(facename, 20, XFontStyle.Italic, options);
    XFont fontBoldItalic = new XFont(facename, 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic, options);

    // The default alignment is baseline left (that differs from GDI+)
    gfx.DrawString("Times (regular)", fontRegular, XBrushes.DarkSlateGray, 0, 30);
    gfx.DrawString("Times (bold)", fontBold, XBrushes.DarkSlateGray, 0, 65);
    gfx.DrawString("Times (italic)", fontItalic, XBrushes.DarkSlateGray, 0, 100);
    gfx.DrawString("Times (bold italic)", fontBoldItalic, XBrushes.DarkSlateGray, 0, 135);

    EndBox(gfx);
}
```

Comment: good info. another question. every time I change it in visual studio I need to clean and rebuild project. is there a quicker way of doing this?

Comment: I press F5, Visual Studio compiles the changes and starts the program. Did you exclude items in the Configuration Manager?

Comment: If this is an official account for PDFsharp can you indicate as such in your profile?

Comment: I dont understand how do I place it in centre then?

Comment: @rogue39nin See the `XStringFormats.Center` parameter value in the question. Calculate the `XRect` for every line, do not use the whole page everywhere as shown in the question.

Comment: Don't try this with PDFsharp-wpf: "Only TopLeft alignment is currently implemented." (PDFsharp-wpf 1.50.5147)

Comment: @Grault You are on the wrong track. You are too negative. The implementation of `XTextFormatter.DrawString` is limited, but `XTextFormatter` is just a sample to get you started. Adding centre-alignment is left as an exercise to the reader. The code here uses `XGraphics.DrawString` where all alignments are implemented. The code shown here works with the WPF build and all other builds.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution

```
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;

string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" +
              "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore" +
              "magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud" +
              "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea "; 

//new document
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
// New Page
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
// The class will provide drwaing related methods for specified page
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

PdfSharp.Drawing.Layout.XTextFormatter tf = new 
PdfSharp.Drawing.Layout.XTextFormatter(gfx);
XFont font = new XFont("Arial", 10);
XRect rect = new XRect(80, 80, 500, 500);
gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.SeaShell, rect);
tf.Alignment = PdfSharp.Drawing.Layout.XParagraphAlignment.Justify;

tf.DrawString(text, fontcuerpo, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.Center);
```

Note: You must not separe the text in lines using /n. It must be a inline string. otherwise it wont work might spected. This will allow yo to use several types of text orientation changing the XStringFormats and also use diferente alignments changing the justify.